'Expression' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
This is the snippet  of the code :
import SQLite
import Foundation

//---------line 12 -------- ↓
    var idCol : Expression<Int64> = Expression("ID")  // column variable that represents the ID column
    

 //---------line 60 -------- ↓
    func insert(tbl: Table, cols: Expression<Int64> ..., vals: Int64 ...){
        do {
            ...
    }
    
//---------line 101 -------- ↓
    func createTable(pk: Expression<Int64>, cols: Expression<Int64> ...) {
        // run the create table if the database connection exists and it doesn't exist already.
        if let definiteDB = db {
            do {
                try _ = definiteDB.scalar(tbl.exists)
                //print("table exists")
            } catch {
                do {
                    //print("table does not exist")
                    try definiteDB.run(tbl.create() {t in
                        t.column(pk, primaryKey: .autoincrement)
                    })
                    for col in cols {
                        try definiteDB.run(tbl.addColumn(notNullToNull(expr: col)))
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}

an error occurred on the line 12, 60 and 101 (labelled in the snippet). The error is 'Expression' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
What can I  modify so that the file will build. I am trying to build it on xcode cloud

How is installed SQLite? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/making-dependencies-available-to-xcode-cloud ?

Installed SQLite by adding Package Dependencies

The iOS 18/macOS 15 SDK now includes a new type called Expression in Foundation. This seems to just be a version of Predicate, except it can output any type, not just Bool.
This causes a name conflict with the Expression type declared in SQLite. You need to write SQLite.Expression to clarify. Or you can declare a type alias:
typealias SQLExpression = SQLite.Expression

